# i am getting output from mysql database in "???acv???" form from jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp, ejb, jstl

hi i am getting my output begining wih 3 '?' marks and ending with 3 /?' marks in form
like '???abc???'
It is case with all the data that i am fetching from database
my code is

```
<c:forEach var="category" items="${categories}">
    <div class="categoryBox">
        <a href="<c:url value='category?${category.id}'/>">
            <span class="categoryLabel"></span>
            <span class="categoryLabelText"><fmt:message key='${category.name}'/>                                 </span>

            <img src="${initParam.categoryImagePath}${category.name}.jpg"
                 alt="<fmt:message key='${category.name}'/>" class="categoryImage">
        </a>
```

kindly help me out with this,it has really hassled me.
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This output comes from the `<fmt:message key='${category.name}'/>` tag. It simply means that you have no key named "abc" in the resource bundle used by fmt:format. It thus displays the key surrounded by question marks to let you know that you forgot to provide a translation for this key.